# Collecting logs from deleting contacts in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, logging, contacts

I'm trying to save informations about deleting contacts in .txt log, but when i'm deleting any contact, nothing happens. If i Block or Unblock Wipe Data, there is info in logs, but no while i'm deleting or moving contacts to trash.

```
@SuppressLint("Range")
    private fun getContactDetails(contactUri: Uri): String {
        val resolver: ContentResolver = contentResolver
        val cursor: Cursor? = resolver.query(contactUri, null, null, null, null)
        cursor?.use {
            if (it.moveToFirst()) {
                val nameIndex = it.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)
                val numberIndex = it.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)
                if (nameIndex != -1 && numberIndex != -1) {
                    val name = it.getString(nameIndex)
                    val number = it.getString(numberIndex)
                    return "Name: $name, Number: $number, Date: ${getCurrentDateTime()}"
                }
            } else {
                // The contact doesn't exist, likely moved to trash
                return "Contact moved to trash: $contactUri, Date: ${getCurrentDateTime()}"
            }
        }
        return ""

    }
```

Also added permissions to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

I tried to retrieve contact information using ContentResolver.query() and Cursor. Initially, I attempted to access contact details through ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, and then checked if the cursor contains the relevant columns (e.g., DISPLAY_NAME and HAS_PHONE_NUMBER) and retrieved the data accordingly. Additionally, I tried to handle the situation when a contact does not exist (moved to trash), which was part of my approach to solving the problem.